# Throttling Throughput on a Metro Ethernet Uplink port using a policer?

Tags: juniper, qos

I have a Juniper EX4200 that acts as a router in our remote data center.  The Juniper is plugged into a 10 mbps metro ethernet link that connects to our office.  The traffic over this link is mostly going to be PCoIP.  The network port that connects to the provider equipment is set to 100/Full, and the provider (Time Warner) has told me that they do not perform any QoS on their MetroE connections.

Should I limit the bandwidth on that port to 10 mbps?  If I do this, will I have to make any changes to my QoS policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change it.  If you change your gear away from the port speed provided to you by your ISP, you can get all kinds of weird errors - dropped packets, speed issues, etc.  Always set your edge gear to the port speed the ISP tells you.  From my experience that's the first thing they ask when troubleshooting issues, so you'll end up setting it back to 100/Full anyway.

Comment: I wasn't talking about changing away from 100/Full.  I was talking about putting in a bandwidth limiter in the switch config that limit the connection to 10 Meg.  Juniper and Cisco call it traffic policing.

Comment: If the pipe from the ISP is 10 Meg, why would you need/want to turn on throttling on your edge gear?  You're already rate limited by the ISP...

Comment: Honestly, it was something that one of our consultants said that we should look into doing when we were doing our QoS design.  Thats why I'm asking.

Comment: It MIGHT do something to make your QoS function more effectively - but I doubt it.  I'm more familiar with Cisco than Juniper, but I've never seen a Cisco device do that configuration to help out with QoS.  At the very least, it's unlikely to actively hurt anything.  I think it's needless complexity, though.

Comment: Thank you!  I've marked your initial post as the answer.

Comment: You can and probably should configure QoS on the device though to correctly prioritize latency sensitive application traffic.